# php - keep in same page after comment processing

Tags: php, forms, post

I've got an index.php where all the texts are displayed. When you click a given title the page sends you,via get, to article.php?idArticle?..., the chosen text.
There, you can comment and the comment processing is made in the same page. But after that, how do I keep the user in the same page (that is, article.php? with the right idArticle for that text)?

As it is now, the user is sent to article.php page, which is expecting a an id via get that it does not get.

Comment: show how you're doing it now, and we'll show you what to fix to get what you want. probably pass the id through the form, if you're not already, and process that at the top of the page, and then were you have something like `if(isset($_GET['idArticle']))` you can also include `|| $_POST['idArticle']`

Comment: you can also try to search for an ajax example and read more about ajax. enjoy learning mate!

Comment: @ElefantPhace,

I think I achieved what I wanted. Thanks for your answers, when what you know is very little any input is very helpful.

I used a hidden input to pass the article ID (something I wasn't really used to)

Comment: @vnpnlz 19,

Thanks, I'll look into it for the future.